# Receiving Failed to resolve errors in Android Studio after updating to version 2.2.3

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I recently updated my Android Studio to a newer version such that I can use Firebase but while building the files it shows the error i.e, failed to resolve javax.inject and 5 more of the same category(annotation, com.google.code, org.hamcrest as such.). I have uploaded a screenshot as well so that it can convey better. I need help with this issue.

[image: screenshot]